# Customs + Electronics per Traveller or as Family

Tags: family

My Wife, Daughter and I are traveling to India for 2 months from US. We would be there arriving at Mumbai.

Can we as a family take 1 iPad + 1 iPhone + 1 Camera + 1 my office laptop with me?
Please note we are 2 Adults and 1 5 year old.

Comment: its not 15 year old, I meant one 5 year old.

Comment: Most countries will assume a kid of 5 years old too young to need expensive customer electronics and will not allow her an extra allowance, but what you mention for the family is less than most business travels take for a single person.